# ServiceStack: AppHost does not support accessing the current Request via a Singleton

Tags: c#, .net, http, servicestack

I'm encountering the following exception when trying using `this.SessionAs<T>` within one of my services:

> "AppHost does not support accessing the current Request via a
>   Singleton"

The offending code is located within the constructor. Strangely, I'm only seeing this when the POST verb is used. I'm not yet sure if this is just a coincidence or not.

My apologies for not providing detailed information at this point. I'm trying to figure out which direction my troubleshooting should take. I'll edit as needed.

Thanks

**Update - Stack trace**

> at ServiceStack.HostContext.GetCurrentRequest() at
>   ServiceStack.SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession[T](ICacheClient cache,
>   IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes) at
>   ServiceStack.Service.SessionAsTUserSession at
>   PeruseServiceStack.Services.Settings.UserService..ctor() at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Container ) at
>   Funq.Container.ResolveImpl[TService](String name, Boolean
>   throwIfMissing)

I will be updating further shortly, I feel like this trace is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide the full Exception StackTrace, it’s unlikely caused by SessionAs API within your Service.

Comment: thanks for the response mythz, added some data to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the StackTrace it looks like you're trying to access `SessionAs<T>` in your `UserService` constructor which you can't do because the Session can only  be accessed within the context of a Request and the Service constructor does not have access to the injected `IRequest` context to be able to access the Session.

So you'd need to move `SessionAs<T>()` calls out of your constructor to within your Service implementation.